# using xpath to find Href in selenium webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, href

i have to find the following href using selenium in java

```
<tr>
   <td>
     <a target="mainFrame" href="reb.php?tiEx=ES"></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

thanks

Comment: Okay... What are you looking for from us? Do you have any existing code that you've tried?

Comment: Did you omit some of the quotes? Shouldn't it be `target="mainFrame" href="reb.php?tiEx=ES"`? Otherwise, the HTML (?) is garbage if you excuse my French.

Comment: yes, by mistake i omited some quotes

Comment: At least specify what language you're using!!!!!

Comment: Your title says "find href" whereas in your XML sample, there is no `href` attribute, but `target`. That does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to find the link depending on the elements it is inside and the uniqueness of the element attribute values on the page, but, from what you've provided, you can rely on the `target` attribute:

```
//a[@target="mainFrame"]
```

You can also narrow it down to the scope of it's parents:

```
//tr/td/a[@target="mainFrame"]
```

Also, you can additionally check the `href` attribute if it is persistent and reliable:

```
//tr/td/a[@target="mainFrame" and @href="reb.php?tiEx=ES"]
```